# jQueryUI tooltip on click handler, reappears after sweetalert dialogue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sweetalert

I'm using jQueryUI tooltip() with [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/).

What I'm trying to achieve should be quite straightforward:

- when user hovers over a link, tooltip displays
- when a user clicks said link, tooltip disappears and SweetAlert prompt appears

What's actually happening though is something like this:

- when a user hovers over a link, tooltip displays (fine)
- when a user clicks said link, tooltip disappears, SweetAlert prompt appears... **but then** when the user clicks off the prompt, **the tooltip randomly reappears** and **stays there until the user clicks elsewhere**!?

I've managed to replicate this in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxw2avfn/). I've tried just `$(document).tooltip();` and as per the fiddle I've tried it with a chained click command to `tooltip("remove")`. Neither appears to work.

I guess SweetAlert's prompt is "breaking" the click event of jQuery UI... but I have no idea how to go about fixing that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `blur` the `div` as soon as you `click` as below. May be a neat trick.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qxw2avfn/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).tooltip({ show: false, hide: false }).click( function () {
          $(this).tooltip("close");
    });

    $('div').on("click", "#test", function() {
        $(this).blur();//Add this here, get the focus outta there
        swal("Test", "Test...", "info");
        return;
    });

});
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)